# Audition channels export 5.1 rear channel to BOTH rears and a front channel

Tags: adobe-audition, 5.1, export

I have a simple 5.1 project. 7 audio clips, each clip is supposed to sound from one and only one speaker. I keyframed it accordingly but Audition exports it weirdly. The audio clips that are supposed to play from one rear speaker are instead playing on BOTH rear speakers AND a front speaker.

View in the project:

[image]

View of the exported audio channels:

[image]

One, and only one channel is supposed to play sound at any given time.

**Edit -**

I used Audacity to remove audio from the wrong channels. It's a stupid workaround, but I got the end result I need.
[image]
For anyone wondering how to export 5.1 (or 7.1+) audio from Audacity, you have to change export preferences:
[image]